# Laravel: In multiple links display data only with certain column values

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

With checkbox I input data in table with values of 1. Now, for example, John has 25 rows with value of 1, Michael 15, Maria 10 etc... Now, I create a bootstrap list with link on it (I will put in attachemnt) and I want when I click on Michael to show me table with only rows where Michael have values of 1, same for John, Maria etc..

[bootstrap list image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jVJS.jpg)

I have more data in there, for example, some relations so when I login with user from New York only displays names where town_id is NY, and that works. Names John, Michael, Maria don't have ID-s, so I can't relate them, it's only columns with variables.

Routes look like this:

> Route::resource('/statistic', 'StatisticController');

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $activists = Activist::where('town_id', Auth::user()->town_id)->get();
    return view('statistic.index', compact('activists'));
}

public function show()
{
    $activists = Activist::where('town_id', Auth::user()->town_id)->paginate(10);
    return view('statistic.show', compact('activists'));
}
```

index.blade.php:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <a href="{{ url('statistic/show') }}" class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">{{$activists->where('work_on_computer', 1) ? $activists->where('john', 1)->count() : '0'}}</span> John</a>
  <a href="{{ url('statistic/show') }}" class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">{{$activists->where('sticking_posters', 1) ? $activists->where('michael', 1)->count() : '0'}}</span> Michael</a>
  <a href="{{ url('statistic/show') }}" class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">{{$activists->where('sharing_flyers', 1) ? $activists->where('maria', 1)->count() : '0'}}</span> Maria</a>
</ul>
```

Now, when I click on link it show me whole table but I can't figure out how to filter only John or Michael or Maria. Sorry if I was confusing.

Comment: pass user(john) Id in url, and then fetch the data according to user id.

Comment: John has no ID, John is only the name of the column. I mention user id only as example.

Comment: how you managed to classify the record(which data related to which user) in database without having the relation?

Comment: No, I have relations with user and towns, that works. That's the $activists variable. Maybe I confused you with mentioning. I don't have relation with values of 1 in column like John, Michael, Maria... Because of that I don't know how to filter rows.

Comment: @NenadM, what are your routes? `statistic/show`, should take (john) as param. ie `statistic/show/{slug}`, is it?

Comment: I didn't take John as param. Route::resource('/statistic/show', 'StatisticController@show');

Comment: update your question with routes, so that I (or someone else) can try to help. your route `statistic/show` need to be configured to have a param.

Comment: I update it, and it's without show, just statistic:
Route::resource('/statistic', 'StatisticController');

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are confused with the resource routes. It work like this -

```
Route::resource('statistic', 'StatisticController');

Actions Handled By Resource Controller

Verb         URI                    Action         Route Name
GET          /statistic             index          statistic.index
GET          /statistic/create      create         statistic.create
POST         /statistic             store          statistic.store
GET          /statistic/{Id}        show           statistic.show
GET          /statistic/{Id}/edit   edit           statistic.edit
PUT/PATCH    /statistic/{Id}        update         statistic.update
DELETE       /statistic/{Id}        destroy        statistic.destroy
```

Hope this will help you to figure out your further action.

Comment: I am confused. I know about the routes and how to check route name when I have to link to certain pages, but I don't know how to deal with params, and I was told that params is what I need for this problem. If you could help me with more detail or post the link with similar solution that would be nice...?

Comment: pass parameter like this -  {{ URL::route('statistic.show', $id) }}